# Devolver resultado a un value de input en action a otro archivo php

Tags: php, html, post

Busco que al procesar en respuesta.php devuelva el valor a la pagina anterior para asi ubicarla en el input. Pienso que esto podria solucionarlo usando $global pero no entiendo mucho su funcionamiento y ya lei que no es aconsejable.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form  action="respuesta.php" method="post">
    <select class="" name="select">
      <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="" value="<?php if (isset($M_codigo)){echo $M_codigo;}  ?>">
    <input type="submit" name"" value="enviar">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

En respuesta php se convierta y devuelva el valor al input

```
<?php
  if ($_POST["select"]=="1") {
    $M_codigo="Valor_devuelto"; 
  }

 ?>
```

Comment: no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta quieres navegar entre paginas y que estan se carguen propia mente en tu pagina principal atraves de un input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende de como llegues de la segunda página a la primera, pero una idea es que utilices sesiones ($_SESSION).

Si te he entendido bien, lo que tendrías que hacer sería:

En respuesta.php asignas el valor que te interesa a una variable de sesion.

```
$_SESSION['valor'] = $_POST["select"];
```

En el primero de los formularios:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['valor'])){
  $valor = $_SESSION['valor'];
else
  $valor = '';

...

<input type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $valor ?>">
```

Y no te olvides de que al utilizar variables de sesion, siempre debes inicializar la sesion nada más abrir las llaves, antes que ninguna otra cosa en tu fichero PHP, osea:

```
<?php
session_start();
```

Haz también alguna [busqueda por Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20sesiones) para ir entendiendolas. Son muy útiles.

Comment: No se me habia ocurrido eso jajaja :D gracias! si de hecho se usar sessions pero recién me percato que podía usarlo asi.